# Calculating boiling point of a solution

Tags: boiling-point

> What is the boiling point of an aqueous solution that has a vapor pressure of $23.0~\text{Torr}$ at $25~^\circ\text{C}$?
>
> $(P^\circ_{\ce{H2O}}=23.78~\text{Torr};~K_\mathrm b= 0.512~^\circ\mathrm{C\ kg/mol})$

To solve this I used the equation $\Delta T_\mathrm b =m\times K_\mathrm b$. I calculated a molality of $1.88247\ \mathrm{mol/kg}$ which I then used to calculate a boiling point of $-0.9638\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$. This answer is apparently wrong and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 4):

If molality is 1.88, then the *change* in boiling point is -0.96 degrees C, not the boiling point itself.

Comment: But if i subtract the change in temperature from the normal boiling point of water (0 C) then we get a boiling point of -0.96 C, which is wrong.

Comment: Water boils at 100 degrees C